# Multiple progress bar in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in data.names">
       <td>
           <progressbar class="progress-striped"  value="{{ data.value.marks }}"            <-- // here is problem
             type="warning">{{ data.value.name }}</progressbar>
      </td>

</tr>
```

Problem:

```
 I am using value="{{ data.value.marks }} *<-- // here is problem*

 don't know how to solve it
```

error
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'data.value.marks' is unexpected, expecting [:]

Need to assign the value dynamically using ng-repeat
please guide me on this

Comment: Don't put `{{data.value.marks}}` between quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value="data.value.marks"` . Do not put curly braces.

Comment: I have another question, how to change the type in progress depends on values                                                         <tr ng-repeat="data in data.names">
       <td>
           <progressbar class="progress-striped"  value="data.value.marks"  type="warning">{{ data.value.name }}</progressbar>
      </td>

</tr>              need to change the type like warning, info, success

Comment: In type="{{data.value.type}}". In your data object add a type key and use as mentioned.